# jQuery dynamically add validation rules to n-number of fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin to validate a form. The form fields are generated dynamically. I have an email:

```
<input type="text" name="customer_email_<?=$i?>" value="" id="customer_email_<?=$i?>" />
```

This input field is in a php loop and can be generated n-number of times. The idea is to check if the entered e-mail is unique. When the user enters something in any of the fields generated I'm sending an AJAX call that is checking in the database if the e-mail is unique.

```
    var pass_count_array = [<?=$js_array?>]; // generated by php

jQuery.each(pass_count_array, function(index, p) {

    //check if the e-mail is unique
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("unique_email_"+p, function(value, element) {
        return check_unique_email(p);
    });  


    var current_email = "customer_email_"+p;
    jQuery("#tair_form").validate({
        rules : {
            current_email: {
                "unique_email_"+p : true
            }
     });        

});
```

The code above is looping through all the fields, adding a custom validation method unique_email_1, unique_email_2, etc.
The problem here is that the validation rules doesn't accept this:

```
"unique_email_"+p : true
```

Any ideas how to apply the custom validation method to every e-mail input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a class to the email fields so that you don't have to search by id but you group by class, that way you just apply a check to the whole class objects.

Loop through them `.each()` for instance, and set off alerts as needed.

Comment: While I agree, I don't think this addresses the real issue. Iskren is trying to use an expression (`"unique_email_"+p`) as a key for initializing validation rules with the jQuery Validation plug-in's API.

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
<input type="text" name="customer_email" value="" id="<?=$i?>" />

$(function(){
    $("input[name=customer_email]").change(function(){
        var email = $(this).attr("id");
        if(check_unique_email(email)==true){
            //callback when email is unique
        }else{
            //callback when email is not unique
        }
    });
});
```